# How to draw in electron using bitmap generated by another process

Tags: node.js, electron

I am new to electron and trying to develop an app. I have an app looking like below

[image]

where black is the toolbar, yellow and blue are javascript code.The problem is the portion is red. I want to draw contents in the red section using bitmap generated by some other process. How do i achieve that. You can think that red section is something like paint app on windows where user can interact draw things etc. So i will need to send the events to the background process and receive the rendered content back. The reason for using the background process is performance consideration.

Not sure if this is even achievable in electron. Pardon my naivety as i am completely new.